# Is there a version of \include and \input for bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, input, include

I'd like to spread out my references between multiple bibtex files. I tried putting all my references into a file called `etho.bib`, then put `\input{etho.bib}` into my main bibtex file. This didn't word. I also tried using `\include` instead of `\input` and `etho.tex` instead of `etho.bib`, but none of that work.

Is there some way for the bibtex compiler to include text from another document into your `.bib` file?

Comment: Your question does not really make much sense. Where exactly would you input a bib file? `\bibliography ` supports giving multiple bib files as a comma separated list

Comment: Inside another bib file. I believe the question makes this clear.

Comment: That does not Really make any sense when you can specify a list of bib files where you needed them. I've never seen any include features in bibtex